# Inferring programmatically terminals and non-terminals in context-free grammars?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to compute the FIRST and FOLLOW sets of a CFG (using Python).

To do this I need to recognise terminals and non-terminals. I can (as a human) read them, but I was wondering if there was computational logic for inferring terminals and non-terminals, if one's given only the grammar.

It sounds like one'd need to construct the parse tree and then label terminals and non-terminals? A terminal is a node that has no childs.

---

One could also use the definition of "terminals" and "non-terminals":

> Terminals
>
> A terminal is a symbol which does not appear on the left-hand side of any production.
>
> Nonterminals
>
> Nonterminals are the non-leaf nodes in a parse tree.

Or perhaps non-terminals are also all of those that don't fit into the definition of terminals.

[http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/PLT/PLT2.1.2b.html](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ekal/PLT/PLT2.1.2b.html)

Comment: This seems like it depends on the exact syntax you use for your BNF. Personally, I'm in the habit of writing my BNFs with <>s around all non-terminals, and ""s around all terminals/string literals, which makes this issue pretty straightforward (I'd probably have to define a \" escape sequence for completeness, but that's about it). Could you describe the exact syntax that you need to be able to parse?

Comment: @Ixrec I'm just looking for a general way for doing this. Could be the kind of labelling that you're mentioning as well.

Comment: I think the general way is just to pick a rigorously precise definition of "non-terminal", which could be "does not appear on the left-hand side of anything" or "is surrounded by double quotes" or something else. As a random example, [yacc seems to rely on single quotes](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly straight-forward. Assuming a grammar like:

```
expr:   ID | STR | NUM | list
list:   ( seq )  
seq:       | expr seq
```

You can collect the symbols in each production (ID, STR, NUM, list, (, seq, ), expr, and *nothing*) and then pull out the production symbols themselves (expr, list, seq). This gives you two sets, the terminals and non-terminals (and *nothing*, which you may want or not depending on your needs).